# Codename One: Query to string picker

Tags: drop-down-menu, codenameone

I would like to populate a picker (accepting strings). This should convert the result of a select query into a string array, so that I can set these as strings for the picker. The user should be able to select from a list of items in the picker.

I would appreciate any help and advice about how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html#_sql):

```
cur = db.executeQuery(query.getText());
boolean next = cur.next();
ArrayList<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
while(next) {
   Row currentRow = cur.getRow();
   String[] currentRowArray = new String[columns];
   strs.add(currentRow.getString("columnName"));   
}

String[] data = new String[strs.size()];
strs.toArray(data);
picker.setStrings(strs);
```